# Output still printed after STDOUT & STDERR redirect

Tags: linux, stream

I've come across something that has awoken my curiosity a few minutes ago. The `gpg` command manages to print its output even though I redirected `stdout` and `stderr` to files.

`$ gpg --decrypt a.gpg 1> a 2> b`

```
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Hello World"
4096-bit RSA key, ID AAAAAAAA, created 2017-07-12 (main key ID BBBBBBBB)

Enter passphrase:
```

How come this whole text is still printed to my terminal even though I redirected all the streams to different files ?

Comment: It's writing to `/dev/tty`, not `stdout`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, ye, explains quite some things. Thanks for the info. If you like you can answer the question and I'd mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: It's not a programming question, it doesn't really belong here, so it's not worth answering.